# Extract only years from strings in different formats in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have data from a public API and I need to extract years from a column in that dataset.

The text from that column has different formats, so let's say it's an array like this:

```
var array = ['ca 1940', '4 October 1935', '1915', 'Undated', 'ca 1921', '5 September 1925']
```

How can I filter this array to have an array like this:

```
var years = magical_method(array); 
// years = ['1940', '1935', '1915', '1921', '1925']
// Remove strings which do not have years and extract years from strings which do have years
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Updated**: I have tried:

```
function removeUndated(year) {
    if (year) {
      return year.match(/[\d]{1}/); 
    }
}
```

to remove the 'Undated' string, but I still don't have any ideas how to extract the years from strings with different formats as above.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Updated........

Comment: Are years always at the end? If not, try `years.join("\n").match(/\b\d{4}\b/g)`, or if yes, try `years.join("\n").match(/\b\d{4}$/gm)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the year value will be the last word of the string so you can split that with respect to whitespace and then get the last word to check if it is a integer or not to satisfy that it is actually a year value.

```js
var array = ['ca 1940', '4 October 1935', '1915', 'Undated', 'ca 1921', '5 September 1925'];
var res = [];
array.forEach((item) => {
  var year = item.split(/\s+/).pop();
  if(parseInt(year)){
    res.push(year);
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. 

However, just wonder if how this problem can be solved with regex in case the year can be anywhere in the strings (a year appears once in a string)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function to create an array and in the call back function you can split the text and get the last value only

```js
var array = ['ca 1940', '4 October 1935', '1915', 'Undated', 'ca 1921', '5 September 1925'];


let x = array.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let x = curr.split(' ');
  if (!isNaN(x[x.length - 1])) {
    acc.push(x[x.length - 1])
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(x)
```